# Protecting global variable with mutex

Tags: c, mutex

supposing that the thread function is executed simultaneously by nbThreads threads, it is necessary to protect the `foo` variable to set it to 0? More generally, is it necessary to protect a global shared variable if we just set it to 0?

```
#include <pthread.h>
int foo = 0;
int nbThreads = 10;
pthread_mutex_t mut;

void thread(void *arg) {
    if (foo == nbThreads - 1) {
        foo = 0;
    } else {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mut);
        foo++;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mut);
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is just as necessary to use the mutex when setting it to zero as it is when changing it. Setting it to zero can still have race conditions with the `foo++` and causing `foo` to have the wrong value.  Yes any variable accessed by multiple threads needs to use this kind of locking mechanism.  In some cases you can use atomic variable which handle locking for you for simple increments / assignments but I've never used them.

Comment: Ok and is it necessary to protect the reading, like in the if?

Comment: In general Yes it certainly would be best.  There are technical reasons why you might get away with not using the Mutex on a simple integer but it's probably better to write a function call read_foo(), set_foo(), increment_foo() that handles the mutex for you and use those functions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is necessary.

The only exception being a variable which is `_Atomic` and therefore guaranteed to be updated with a single write. Otherwise, strange bugs might theoretically happen, such as only half of the binary value getting set to zero.

Depending on the nature of the application, it may of course also be a bug if another thread writes data to the variable and you immediately overwrite that data with your `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, any operation that writes or reads a shared variable must be atomically executed. Here's an article which explains all about it : [What_is_an_atomic_operation](http://eversystems.eu/Document/28/What_is_an_atomic_operation). This may also be helpful [Mutex Lock Code Examples](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-5257/sync-12/index.html).